# Collection for Objects and find them by the superclass

Tags: java, collections

I need a Collection to store a couple of objects. I want to access them with there Class or Superclass.

For example: `collection.get(Object.class)` would return all Objects.

Is there a ready made class that I can use or do I need to write my own. In that case I would use a `HashMap<Class,Object>` as base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java 8 Streams for retrieving the required instances with a relatively short syntax. For example :

```
List<SomeType> objects = collections.filter(o -> o instanceof SomeType).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course such code requires iterating over your entire Collection. If the Collection is large and performance is an issue, you should probably store your objects in some data structure that allows faster retrieval (perhaps `HashMap`).

Comment: Looks like a nice pice of code, but I have to add that the code is used by an android device too. Not sure if that is possible with java8.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8 consider the previous post solution else you could use apache

```
 CollectionUtils.filter( youList, new Predicate(){
     public boolean evaluate( Object input ) {
        return input instanceof youClass;
     }
  } );
```

Comment: This answer is correct too and it will work with android. But I would prefer an own class before I include a 5MB jar-file.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in convenient way.

However, you could easily define a method to do it:

```
<T> List<T> getAllElements(Collection<?> collection, Class<T> targetClass) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Object obj : collection)
        if(targetClass.isInstance(obj))
            result.add(targetClass.cast(obj));
    return result;
}
```

This is essentially the same as Eran's lambda solution, but without using Java 8 features.

Comment: I think this answer fits my problem best, but I set Eran's answer to the correct one, cause I forget to tell about android in the Question.

Comment: Why is there an leading `<T>` before `List<T>`? Can you give me a hint for google that?

Comment: @doev It's a type parameter for the method.